# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub XmlPullParserFactory

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, xml-parsing, compiler-errors

I want to run one of my java classes using Intellij Idea 14, and I am having trouble with trying to get rid of this compile-time error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(XmlPullParserFactory.java:13)
```

And I am following this site: http://xmlpull.org/v1/download/unpacked/doc/quick_intro.html for guidance with xmlpullparser and xmlpullparserfactory.

Now, I have downloaded one implementation of XMLPULL API V1, kxml2.jar, and I have added it to my classpath, correct me if I am wrong but this is what I did:

Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > + > Jars or Directories > file location

What else do I need to do?

Main Method:

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    File file = new File( "testmap.tmx" );
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput( new FileReader( file ) );

    TiledXMLParser parser = new TiledXMLParser( xpp );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` if you try to use something from the Android platform jar (`android.jar`) outside of Android. You would need to build and run this as an Android application via a device or emulated device or else change your main() method to a JUnit test method like this and then run it:

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    File file = new File( "testmap.tmx" );
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput( new FileReader( file ) );

    TiledXMLParser parser = new TiledXMLParser( xpp );
}
```